# How are the rulings for menstruation defined?

Tags: women, fiqh, menses

How are the rulings for menstruation/menses for our sisters defined according to the different fiqh schools?

I mean the duration, how a female can be sure her menses really ended, etc.

Comment: Related https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/40872/determining-your-period